# jQuery Mobile List: On item click AND on split button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying for hours now:

I want to have a dynamically generated list which has split buttons to the right. These buttons should fire an onClick-Event like every button does. The problem is that an click on these buttons fires the onClick event of the listview, which should do something else.

Clicking on the item approves it and the split-button deletes the entry for example.

Is this possible? I couldn't find any tutorials or advices in the docs..

Comment: Probably. Is it possible that the code you've tried could be posted so we have something to look at?

Answer (score 1):

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/HT8pA/1/)**

When adding the dynamic list items, apply identifying classes to the 2 anchors. In this example, the main anchor is mainLink and the split button is deleteItem. Then setup click handlers for the 2 classes uses event delegation ($(document).on("click", ".mainLink", ... so that dynamically added items will be handled:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {

    var dynamicItems = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        dynamicItems += '<li data-itemid=' + i + '><a href="#" class="mainLink"><h2>ITEM' + i + '</h2><p>Description</p><a class="deleteItem" href="#"></a>';
    }

    $("#thelist").empty().append(dynamicItems).listview("refresh");

    $(document).on("click", ".mainLink", function () {
        alert("Approve " + $(this).parents("li").data("itemid"))
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".deleteItem", function () {
        alert("Delete " + $(this).parents("li").data("itemid"))
    });

});
```